# Reading a dataconfig.config encrypted file

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration-files

I've a dataconfiguration.config encrypted file for an application on ASP.NET Framework 3.5
I need to change my connection string, how can i decrypted and read this file? 
Security it's not an issue, I'm on a development enviroment.

Any tip will be preciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Leandro - If you have encrypted the file, then you must be knowing what decryption algorithim to use to decrypt it.

Comment: I dont really know, thats im trying to know right now. If I open the file, i just read a binary file, not a xml or something like. There is some place where i can know how was encrypted? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hi Bibhu. Not, not really. It's an application with a very very bad KT, it was migrated from other team that doesnt exists any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to encrypt ASP.NET configuration sections (such as ConnectionStrings) is to use [Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx).  However if your file does not read as XML, this method was not used or was not the only level of encryption used.  It sounds like maybe there was a third party tool involved.

If I were you, I would probably create a new config file, and find everywhere in the project the old config file was referenced to point things at the new file.

If that is not possible, maybe you'd have better luck posting a question in a general cryptography category or doing some searches on the subject.  I know some encryption can be identified by look at the encrypted data.  Some encryption schemes are designed specifically to hide that though.  Good luck.